# i3lock, display same image in a configuration dual monitor?

Tags: multiple-monitors

Is it possible to have the same image on two different monitors? I'm use Ubuntu 18.04 with `i3wm`. I have a script for custom `i3lock`, with a image of Morty (Rick & Morty). But, in the dualmonitor, the image stay in the middle of the monitors. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use a single monitor instead of the center of both, you need to set up `SDL_VIDEO_FULLSCREEN_HEAD`.  Depending on how you're loading `i3`, you can do this by specifying in `~/.xinitrc` \ `.xsessionrc`, or for `i3lock` when it is run by `i3`:

```bsh
export SDL_VIDEO_FULLSCREEN_HEAD=0  # First monitor
```

`0` is the number of the monitor, starting with zero.  For a dual monitor setup, you can choose between `0` and `1`.  Typically, `0` will be the monitor you see BIOS POST and the initial Linux console.

#### `i3lock` only

The most simple way to achieve this would be to set this variable for `i3lock`, so by editing your `~/.config/i3/config`:

```
...
exec --no-startup-id i3lock ...
```

```
...
exec --no-startup-id SDL_VIDEO_FULLSCREEN_HEAD=0 i3lock ...
```

#### All programs in `i3`

To do this for all applications for your user within `i3`, you would add this line to `~/.xinitrc` \ `.xsessionrc` itself.

Once this variable is defined when your window manager starts, full screen applications will all display on this one screen, and not split over both.  You may be able to test this in a single terminal by exporting the variable and launching `i3lock`, but you must make the change as described earlier and restart `i3` for it to work for everything properly.

One issue you may find is that `~/.xinitrc` \ `.xsessionrc` are not being brought in by `i3`.  One [recommendation](https://faq.i3wm.org/question/4126/sessions-environment-variables.1.html) is to instead add these configurations to `~/.profile`:

```bsh
if [ "$0" = "/usr/sbin/lightdm-session" -a "$DESKTOP_SESSION" = "i3" ]; then
    # Do stuff
fi
```

Personally, I have abandoned both `GDM` and `LightDM` and instead login to the console/tty, and `startx`, similar to the above suggestion, using `Xsession` configured with `i3` as the default, which causes proper initialization of `~/.xinitrc`:

```bsh
#
# ~/.bash_profile
#
[ -e ~/.profile ] && source ~/.profile
[ -e ~/.bashrc ] && source ~/.bashrc

if [ $XDG_VTNR -le 2 ] && [ $TERM != "screen-256color"  ]; then
    startx /etc/X11/Xsession -- :1 -nolisten tcp
fi
```

---

#### Desktop Background/Wallpaper

To set up a wallpaper, which is likely different than `i3lock`, you can use `feh`.  `feh` will set up both monitors the same (by default):

```bsh
feh --bg-center /path/to/desktop.png --image-bg '#f1fa8c'
```

Or, in your `~/.config/i3/config`:

```
exec_always --no-startup-id sleep 5 ; feh --bg-center /path/to/desktop.png --image-bg '#f1fa8c'
```

---

Alternatively, you can set up `xscreensaver`, which handles dual screen monitors great, by displaying the screen saver on both, and putting the login prompt in the center of a single monitor.